# NativeScript Android: WebView not working on Android Device

Tags: android, typescript, android-webview, nativescript

I use a WebView for my NativeScript-Application. That WebView has an url `https://$myUrl` where a `.html` is located. In that html an `.png` is referenced.

My code:

From my Application:

```
<GridLayout style="width: 100%" columns="*" rows="*" >

    <WebView #myView src="https://$myUrl" (loadStarted)="loadStarted()" (loadFinished)="loadFinished()"></WebView>
    <ActivityIndicator [busy]="isLoading" [visibility]="isLoading ? 'visible' : 'collapse'" horizontalAlignment="center" verticalAlignment="center"></ActivityIndicator>

</GridLayout>
```

in my `.ts`-file:

```
loadStarted() {
        this.isLoading = true;
        let webView = (<WebView>this.myView.nativeElement);
        if (webView.android) {
            webView.android.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
            webView.android.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
        }
    }


loadFinished() {
    this.isLoading = false;
}
```

In my `Manifest.xml` I set:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

So everything worked fine last year and now it still works fine on my emulators (Android and iOS). Now I inserted a new `.png` on the server and it does not display on my device.

Is that something with the WebView? We tried to swap out the `.png` last year and everything worked fine.

I really do not know why this does not work any more?

Comment: Given that your code works with a specific *.png and does not work with another one I would suggest to check if the image is correctly referenced from your server and check the extension. Also, you might want to try to load other PNG files to see how your code handles them.

Comment: @NickIliev When I enter the given url via browser there is no problem and everything is displaying correctly.  I am going to try with another PNG.

Comment: Trying with another PNG did not change the outcome, so it should not be related to that